# Why is my bisect tool not working?

Tags: bisect

It says Report: "Error Selected edges/faces required". It might be because i am working on a metaball that has "Object> Apply> Visual Geometry to Mesh"

Answer (score 0):

You can restart blender and then maybe it'll work fine.
If it still not working go and try this...
menu>mesh>bisect I know only these two methods.
Hope it'll help you.